# How to assign values to pixels in an image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have an image and I want to assign value to particular colors. Here is the code:

```
for x in range(mask.shape[0]):         //my image is of size:(400,300)
    for y in range(mask.shape[1]):
        if r[x,y] == 1:
            mask[x,y]=1
        elif g[x,y] == 1:
            mask[x,y] = 1
        else
            mask[x,y] = 0
```

here r,g are generated from cv.split(mask).

Is this the correct way to do so?

Comment: rule #1 : **never** loop over pixels. (there's always a builtin function for what you want already).

Comment: Show the code. I can't imagine why that wouldn't work.

Comment: @MarkRansom I have not written any code. I am not from coding background. Can you help me. I just have an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: "I used two for loops" implies that you wrote some code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I want to assign value to a particular color. That's why I was using two for loops.

Comment: it's mask[row,col] in opencv, not x,y. also you got the shape[] indices wrong (should be 0 and 1, not 1 and 2) again, please **don't** do it this way. instead use cv2.inRange() to threshold your image.

Comment: @berak I didn't understand your last part.

Comment: rather apply[inRange](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.inRange) on your 3-channel img, than splitting it and doing your (horrible) for-loops

Comment: @berak Can you tell me how to use inrange function to set the values of red and green colors to 1 and for other colors set the value to 0.

Comment: Your `r,g,b` images probably range from 0-255, not just 0 and 1. Same with your `mask` output. Is that the problem you're having?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes that is the problem I was facing. Thank you for pointing out that. The r,g,b images range from 0-255 but there is no problem with the mask. I am assigning values to red and green pixels(so these values can be 0 or 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In opencv you index/slice pixels in an image just like in numpy:

```
img[x,y] = 42  #sets the value of pixel at x,y
p = img[x,y]  #gets the value of pixel at x,y
```

It's hard to tell what you might be doing wrong though without seeing any code.

For colors, you will have a third dimension to worry about:

```
img[x,y,0] = 42  #sets the BLUE value of pixel at x,y
v = img[x,y,1]  #gets the GREEN value of pixel at x,y
```

Remember that in opencv, the default order for colors is BGR, not RGB.